# How to update scope var from Math expression and another scope var?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

Not sure if I made myself clear on my question but what I really want is to update the `min-width` with `ng-style` for each `<li>` within an `ng-repeat` to equal the percentage of `100 / array.length`.

My first solution is simply:

`<li ng-style="{'min-width': (100 / array.length) + '%'}">`

This works, but I don't like the Math expression in the view, I'd rather have it in the controller. Something in the lines of:

`$scope.percentage = (100 / $scope.array.length) + '%'`

`<li ng-style="{'min-width': percentage}"`

The problem with this approach is that when the array contents change, `percentage` is not changed. I could add a `$watchCollection` to `array` and update `percentage` there, but it doesn't feel right, like I'm missing a better approach. Am I?

If not, which solution do you prefer? Math expression in the view, or `$watchCollection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define percentage as a function.

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/waxolunist/5bnhj4vt/6/

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="AController">
        <ul>
            <li class="red" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-style="{'width': percentage()}">{{item}}</li>
        </ul>

    <button ng-click="addItem()">addItem</button>
    </div>


</div>
```

**JS**:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('AController', function($scope) {

    $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

    $scope.percentage = function() {
        return 100/$scope.items.length + '%';
    }

    $scope.addItem = function() {
        $scope.items.push($scope.items.length + 1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a function for exemple:

```
$scope.getTableWidth = function(){
   return (100 / $scope.array.length) + '%';
}
```

And

```
<li ng-style="{'min-width': getTableWidth()}">
```

So at each DOM refesh your array length is refreshed even if it changed.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

What if you use a function instead:

```
$scope.percentage = function () {
  return (100 / $scope.array.length) + '%';
}

// or give array as parameter

$scope.percentage = function (array) {
  return (100 / array.length) + '%';
}
```

And then use it:

```
<li ng-style="{'min-width': percentage()}">

Or

<li ng-style="{'min-width': percentage(array)}">
```

And yet another way would be using a filter:

```
// here it's presumed that you have 
//     var app = angular.module(...);
// somewhere above
app.filter('widthPercentage', function () {
    return function (items) {
        return 100 / items.length + '%';
    };
});
```

And using it

```
<li ng-style="{'min-width': (array | widthPercentage)}">
```